# Difference between C++11 std::bind and boost::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-bind, stdbind

Is there any difference between the two? Or am I safe to replace every occurrence of `boost::bind` by `std::bind` in my code and thereby remove the dependence on Boost?

Comment: I believe `std::bind` was pretty much copied from `boost::bind` when they came out with C++11, as with quite a few other things.

Comment: The question is about the "pretty much" part though. With some of the things that were lifted from Boost, minor changes were made.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

- `boost::bind` [has overloaded relational operators](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/#bind.purpose.overloaded_operators_new_in_boos), `std::bind` does not.
- `boost::bind` [supports non-default calling conventions](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/#bind.implementation.stdcall), `std::bind` is not guaranteed to (standard library implementations may offer this as an extension).
- `boost::bind` provides a direct mechanism to allow one to *prevent* eager evaluation of nested bind expressions ([`boost::protect`](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/#bind.purpose.using_nested_binds_for_function_)), `std::bind` does not. (That said, one can use `boost::protect` with `std::bind` if they want, or trivially reimplement it on their own.)
- `std::bind` provides a direct mechanism to allow one to treat any user defined functor as a nested bind expression in order to *force* eager evaluation ([`std::is_bind_expression`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/is_bind_expression): [func.bind.isbind]/1, [func.bind.bind]/10), `boost::bind` does not.

Answer (score 26):

Besides the several differences cited on the other answers, here are two other differences:

- `boost::bind` seems to  deal with overloaded function names in some situations, whereas `std::bind` does not deal with them in the same way.  See  [c++11 faq](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-function)

(using gcc 4.7.2, boost lib version 1_54)

```
void foo(){}
void foo(int i){}

auto badstd1 = std::bind(foo);  
//compile error: no matching function for call to bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>)
auto badstd2 = std::bind(foo, 1); 
//compile error: no matching function for call to bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>)
auto std1 = std::bind(static_cast<void(*)()>(foo)); //compiles ok
auto std2 = std::bind(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(foo), 1); //compiles ok
auto boost1 = boost::bind(foo, 1); //compiles ok
auto boost2 = boost::bind(foo); //compiles ok
```

So if you simply replaced all `boost::bind` with `std::bind`, your build could break.

- `std::bind` can seamlessly bind to c++11 lambda types, whereas `boost::bind` as of boost 1.54 seems to require input from the user (unless return_type is defined). See [boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_function_objects)

(using gcc 4.7.2, boost lib version 1_54)

```
auto fun = [](int i) { return i;};
auto stdbound = std::bind(fun, std::placeholders::_1);
stdbound(1);

auto boostboundNaive = boost::bind(fun, _1);  //compile error.
// error: no type named ‘result_type’ ...
auto boostbound1 = boost::bind<int>(fun, _1); //ok
boostbound1(1);
auto boostbound2 = boost::bind(boost::type<int>(), fun, _1); //ok
boostbound2(1);
```

So, if you simply replaced all `std::bind` with `boost::bind`, your build could also break.

Answer (score 16):

Besides the listed above, boost::bind has an important extension point: get_pointer() function that allows integrating boost::bind with any smart pointer, eg. ATL::CComPtr etc.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html#get_pointer

As a result, with boost::bind you can also bind a weak_ptr:
http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/01/189529.php

Comment: The `INVOKE` functionality in the standard works with any smart pointer that support `operator*`

Answer (score 8):

I don't have the full answer but `std::bind` will use variadic templates rather than parameter lists.

The placeholders are in `std::placeholders` as in `std::placeholders::_1`rather than the global namespace.

I alias the namespace to stdph with

```
namespace stdph=std::placeholders;
```

Apart from that I have had no problems updating to C++11

Comment: When porting existing boost::bind code that use placeholders, adding "using namespace std::placeholders;" at the top of the file puts the placeholders into the global namespace.  Very handy.

Comment: the problem is, when porting you usually end up with boost bind still wrangling it;s way through somehow and you end up with the standard and boost placeholders.

Comment: It depends on the project I guess.  I mechanically removed all my boost function.hpp and bind.hpp includes from a decent size project with sed and the above namespace directive worked out fine.  If you have boost bind in some header that you can't change, I see how things could get ugly.

Comment: @goertzenator : I think the issue is more about use of any _other_ Boost libraries, as I'd wager at least a third of Boost uses `boost::bind` directly or indirectly.