# std::bind a bound function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, bind

I'm having trouble in detecting why the heck is this not compiling. I've got some lambda function that returns a `std::function` based on some argument.

I've narrowed down my problem to this snippet(which doesn't use lambdas, but reproduces my error perfectly):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


struct foo {
    template<class T>
    void bar(T data) {
        std::cout << data << "\n";
    }
};

void some_fun(const std::function<void(int)> &f) {
    f(12);
}

int main() {
    foo x;
    auto f = std::bind(&foo::bar<int>, x, std::placeholders::_1);
    auto w = std::bind(some_fun, f);
    w();
}
```

The call to `w()` produces one of those lovely gcc error outputs in which I can't figure out what's going wrong. This is the error echoed by gcc 4.6.1:

```
g++ -std=c++0x    test.cpp   -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20:7: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (foo::*)(int)>(foo, std::_Placeholder<1>)>))(const std::function<void(int)>&)>) ()’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1130:11: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1201:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = void (*)(const std::function<void(int)>&), _Bound_args = {std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (foo::*)(int)>(foo, std::_Placeholder<1>)>}]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1215:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = void (*)(const std::function<void(int)>&), _Bound_args = {std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (foo::*)(int)>(foo, std::_Placeholder<1>)>}]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1229:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = void (*)(const std::function<void(int)>&), _Bound_args = {std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (foo::*)(int)>(foo, std::_Placeholder<1>)>}]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/functional:1243:2: note: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}, _Result = _Result, _Functor = void (*)(const std::function<void(int)>&), _Bound_args = {std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (foo::*)(int)>(foo, std::_Placeholder<1>)>}]
```

Here, `f` should be some callable object which takes an int as argument and calls `x.bar(int)` using it. On the other hand, `w` is just a callable object which calls `some_fun(f)`, being `f` the callable object mentioned above, which has the signature expected by `some_fun`'s parameter.

Am I missing something? I probably don't know how to actually mix `std::bind` and  `std::function`.

Comment: It seems to work when you replace auto with `std::function<void(int)>` for f.

Comment: This might not be an answer to your problem.. but have you considered using the native lambda-functions coming with C++11 (which make std::bind unnecessary)?

Comment: In Boost we have `protect` for cases like this, but it doesn't seem to have make it to the standard.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg nice one, didn't try that. It does work that way.

Comment: So the question is, what *is* auto taking the type of? Perhaps it's an `std::mem_fn` or something. I haven't worked with this a lot.

Comment: @chris yes, apparently bind is changing the expected(at least by me) type of `f`. I mean, I know that `std::bind` return some form of magic type, but hadn't thought it couldn't be used as an  `std::function`.

Comment: `f` isn't a `std::function`, but rather some unnamable bind-expression type. You have to convert it to `std::function` explicitly. This is one of the cases where you mustn't use `auto`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, if you can put in a bit more *why*, that would make a great answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB I agree with chris ;)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10555796/636019), specifically the part about preventing eager evaluation (you can't without changing the type, because of `std::is_bind_expression<>`).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) expressions, like their `boost::bind` predecessors, support a type of composition operation.  Your expression for `w` is roughly equivalent to

```
auto w=std::bind(some_fun,  std::bind(&foo::bar<int>, x, std::placeholders::_1) );
```

Nesting binds in this manner is interpreted as

1. Calculate the value of `x.bar<int>(y)` where `y` is the first parameter passed into the resulting functor.
2. Pass that result into `some_fun`.

But `x.bar<int>(y)` returns void, not any function type.  That's why this doesn't compile.

As K-ballo points out, with `boost::bind`, you can fix this problem with `boost::protect`.  As Kerrek SB and ildjarn point out, one way around this issue is: don't use `auto` for `f`.  You don't want `f` to have the type of a bind expression.  If `f` has some other type, then `std::bind` won't attempt to apply the function composition rules.  You might, for instance, give `f` the type `std::function<void(int)>`:

```
std::function<void(int)> f = std::bind(&foo::bar<int>, x, std::placeholders::_1);
auto w = std::bind(some_fun, f);
```

Since `f` doesn't literally have the type of a bind expression, `std::is_bind_expression<>::value` will be false on `f`'s type, and so the `std::bind` expression in the second line will just pass the value on verbatim, rather than attempting to apply the function composition rules.

Answer (score -3):

`some_fun` wants argument of type `const std::function<void(int)> &`.

std::bind returns "a function object of unspecified type T" (look at provided link, section "Return value"), that you are trying to pass as some_fun argument.

It seems this causes problem, because this argument type is not expected.

Look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: This is not the underlying problem at all -- `std::is_bind_expression<>` and its behavior is.