# bind binded function as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, function-pointers, boost-bind

I have a class `foo` with a method `bar` which takes *something callable* (function-pointer/ functor). this callable something should be passed to another method `doit` as an binded element with a third method `bar_cb` method.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class foo {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void bar(T&& t) {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
        doit(std::bind(&foo::template bar_cb<T>, this, std::forward<T>(t)));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void doit(T&& t) {
        std::cout << "doit\n";
        t();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void bar_cb(T&& t) {
        std::cout << "bar_cb\n";
        t();
    }
};


void lala() {
    std::cout << "lala\n";
}

class functor {
public:
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "functor::operator()\n";
    }
};


int main() {
    foo f;
    functor fn;
    f.bar(fn);
    f.bar(std::bind(lala));  // error

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine for `functors` but not for binded functions as argument for `foo::bar` (`lala` in my example). Is it possible to pass an unknowable type to a method and bind it in this method as an argument to another (and if so how)?

I know I could wrap a functor (`std::function` for example) around the function but since I can call an unknowable type I think there is a way to also bind it (I think I'm just missing something simple).

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0efae8f2b5d8d1ac) a link to an example.

Comment: What is the actual (higher-level) problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the problem is that i want to have a class which takes either a functor or a function and call other functors with this `callable` as parameter. the real code is an variadic template class with different functors as template parameters. however, i tried to summerize the problem into a simple non-template class to understand what is wrong. also i want to avoid the overhead of `std::function`.

Comment: You are running into `bind`'s special handling for bind expressions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777421/stdbind-a-bound-function

Comment: @T.C. yes i know :( i've read some stuff about this. and it is quit hard because i don't understand good enough how bind is working under the hood.

Comment: Use a lambda in place of `std::bind`, perhaps? [Live example](http://rextester.com/MVYS30054). Not sure about the implications on perfect forwarding, though.

Comment: Write an `unbind` that takes a bind expression and wraps it in a type that is not a bind expression?  Yet otherwise behaves the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is that your `bar_cb(T&&)` doesn't deduce the template argument because the template argument is actually specified when using `&foo::template bar_cb<X>` with some template argument `X`. The `bind()` expression will, however, copy the bound function, i.e., it may or may not have the type which would be deduced. Also, `std::bind()` will *not* pass `bind()`-expression through but will rather *call* them!

The easiest work around is to *not* use `std::bind()` to bind the function but rather to use a lambda function:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(T&& t) {
    std::cout << "bar\n";
    doit([=](){ this->bar_cb(t); });
}
```

Doing so let's the compiler deduce the correction argument type for `bar_cb()` (with C++14 you may want to use the capture `[this,t = std::forward<T>(t)]` although your `bar_cb()` still won't see an rvalue).

To pass an already `bind()`-expression through another `bind()`-expression, without having `bind()` consider the inner `bind()`-expression a `bind()`-expression you need to make it look as if it is not a `bind()`-expression. You could do so with a thin function wrapper:

```
template <typename Fun>
class unbinder {
    Fun fun;
public:
    template <typename F>
    unbinder(F&& fun): fun(std::forward<F>(fun)) {}
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
        -> decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        return fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
template <typename Fun>
auto unbind(Fun&& fun)
    -> unbinder<Fun> {
    return unbinder<Fun>(std::forward<Fun>(fun));
}
```

Since the function stored in the `bind()` expression will be passed by lvalue, you'll need a different declaration for your `bar_cb()`, however:

```
template<typename T>
void bar_cb(T& t) {
    ...
}
```

With that, you can register the `bind()`-expression using

```
f.bar(unbind(std::bind(lala)));
```

If you want to use `f.bar(std::bind(lala))` you'll need a conditional definition of `bar()`: if it receives a `bind()`-expression it needs to automatically hide the fact that it is a `bind()`-expression by applying `unbind()` or something similar:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_bind_expression<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value>::type
bar(T&& t) {
    std::cout << "bar (non-bind)\n";
    doit(std::bind(&foo::template bar_cb<T>, this, std::forward<T>(t)));
}
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_bind_expression<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value>::type
bar(T&& t) {
    std::cout << "bar (bind)\n";
    doit(std::bind(&foo::template bar_cb<unbinder<T>>, this, unbind(std::forward<T>(t))));
}
```

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. i will try both. btw, is there a specific reason why you pass by value in the lambda function.

Comment: Capturing the bound arguments by value resembles the original construction using `srd::bind()` more closely (if you wanted to capture the value by reference wirh `std::bind()` you'd have used `std::ref()`). Also, it seems to be the more failure-proof starting point as there are no life-time issues. Finally, capturing generic arguments by value gives the user of the function the choice to override the default, also using `std::ref()`.