# using std::bind to bind the result from another std::bind as an argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I need to capture a move-only bind object in a lambda, and I'm trying to use a workaround with std::bind to obtain move-capturing semantics with C++11 as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744730/52207). I've reduced a test case that shows the move-only part of it isn't relevant to the compile error I'm encountering, so most generally this question is about **using std::bind to bind the result from another std::bind as an argument**.

Here's a minimal example reduced from more complex code:

```
void g(int);

void test() {
    auto fn = std::bind(g, 0);
    using Fn = decltype(fn);
//    auto bound = [fn] {};
    auto bound = std::bind([] (Fn) {}, fn);
    bound();
}
```

This produces the error "No matching function for call to '__invoke'". The complete error output is [available here](https://gist.github.com/jfirebaugh/01805dc7c4db10d5c154).

The equivalent simpler case using a capturing lambda (commented out in the above code) works fine, of course. But in my actual code I would need to write `[fn = std::move(fn)] {}` and I don't have the option of requring C++14 yet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are running into [`bind`'s special handling for bind expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777421/stdbind-a-bound-function).

Comment: Anyway, here's a possible fix: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3084ebd679f723a7