# Difference between boost::thread and std::thread

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have a place where things work using boost::thread(example using boost::asio)

```
  std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > threads;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < io_services_.size(); ++i)
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread(new boost::thread(
          boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, io_services_[i])));
    threads.push_back(thread);
  }
```

If I try to use it with std:thread I get compile error:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->ioServices.size(); ++i)
{
    std::thread thread(&boost::asio::io_service::run, ioServices[i]); // compile error std::thread::thread : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments   

    threads.push_back(std::move(thread));
}
```

Comment: Relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555566/is-there-any-difference-between-c11-stdbind-and-boostbind

Comment: Your compile error doesn't contain a call to `boost::bind`?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz updated the title, as this is pertaining to difference between boost::tread and std::thread

Comment: @Chad tnx for pointing that out. updated

Comment: I still don't see the update.  You're calling the `std::thread` constructor with two arguments that it's not expecting.  If you instead constructed a `boost::bind` object with those same two parameters, I would expect this to compile and work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, both should work, since `std::thread` has a vararg constructor which basically invokes its arguments as if it were used with `std::bind`.  The problem appears to be that, at least in my implementation (gcc 4.6.3), neither `std::thread` nor `std::bind` can determine which overload of `run` was intended, resulting in a compilation error.

However, if you use `boost::bind`, this works. So I would use, and manually perform the bind manually:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->ioServices.size(); ++i)
{
    std::thread thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, ioServices[i])); 

    threads.push_back(std::move(thread));
}
```

Edit:  It appears that `boost::bind` succeeds because it's got a ton of overloads, and based on the number of arguments it was provided, during overload resolution and template substitution of `boost::bind` it can determine which overload of `boost::asio::io_service::run` was intended.

However, since `std::bind` and `std::thread` rely on a vararg tempalte arguments, both overloads of `run` are equally valid, and the compiler cannot resolve which one to use.  This ambiguity results in a failure to determine which results in the failures you are seeing.

So another solution is:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
typedef std::size_t (boost::asio::io_service::*signature_type)();
signature_type run_ptr = &boost::asio::io_service::run;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->ioServices.size(); ++i)
{
    std::thread thread(run_ptr, ioServices[i]); 

    threads.push_back(std::move(thread));
}
```

Comment: what I find interesting here is that io_service::run is not a static method and don't know how boot::bind can bind to that...

Comment: the first solution proposed works also. at least it compiles under vs2012

Comment: @Gmt: `boost::bind` (and `std::bind`) work with Pointer to Member Functions by assuming that the first argument provided (either at bind time or invocation time) is either a reference or pointer to the appropriate type, and then using that as the object to call the member function on.

Comment: @DaveS missed the part with "invocation time". I thought that in case of member one had to do std::bind(&instance_member, objInstance, member_args..)