# migrating from boost to std

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

We have an "old" C++ project here, in which it heavily utilizes the `boost` classes (such as `shared_ptr`). Now we want to migrate the project to C++11.

My questions are:
1. Is it mandatory to switch to `std` casting operators?
2. What's the benefits of migrating to `std`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "casting operators"? `shared_ptr` is a class. Also, the benefits of using the standard library should be obvious (i.e. portability, ease of use (you don't have to install Boost) etc.).

Comment: You are right. Probably I used the wrong term. I meant the `class`es.
I'm agree with portability but we have to include boost anyway since we are using it for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not mandatory to use the std versions of features that were first implemented in boost. There aren't any big advantages to using std versions over boost's implementation, except if perhaps it enables you to eliminate a dependency on boost.

In the process of adopting features from boost, improvements were made to the std versions. I'm not sure to what degree those improvements have also been applied back to boost; it's likely that most have been, but possibly not all.

Using a variety of std implementations may flush out bugs where you're relying on some peculiarity of one implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I see from the previous comments that by casting operators you meant smart pointers. In that case the transition should be trivial.
In other cases, as in migrating from boost::thread to std::thread, the path is not so obvious.
Check [this post by Anthony Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241993/is-it-smart-to-replace-boostthread-and-boostmutex-with-c11-equivalents/7242294#7242294) on the difference between boost::threads and std::threads

Also,[this one on boost::bind vs std::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555566/is-there-any-difference-between-c11-stdbind-and-boostbind)

The main advantage is support and not requiring to have to deploy boost. (Note: As far as support goes, the boost mailing list will sometimes reply faster than commercial compilers will)