# Difference between std::bind and boost::bind with polymorphism

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, boost-bind, stdbind

I have a derived class from which I bind a virtual function that I did not override in this class, so I'm hoping to call the one of the parent class. 
It works nice with boost (1.55), but if I switch to std::bind from C++11, it refuse to compile with

> error C2100: illegal indirection
>   1>          functional(1152) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Rx std::_Pmf_wrap<_Pmf_t,_Rx,_Farg0,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,>::operator ()(_Wrapper &) const' being compiled
>   1>          with
>   1>          [
>   1>              _Rx=bool,
>   1>              _Pmf_t=bool (__thiscall Base::* )(void),
>   1>              _Farg0=Base,
>   1>              _V0_t=std::_Nil,
>   1>              _V1_t=std::_Nil,
>   1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
>   1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
>   1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
>   1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
>   1>              =std::_Nil,
>   1>              _Wrapper=Derived
>   1>          ]

Here is a minimum code

```
class Runnable { virtual bool Run() =0;};
class Base : public Runnable { bool Run() {/*do stuff*/ return true;}};
class Derived : public Base {};

Derived d;
std::function<bool()> f = std::bind(&Derived::Run,std::ref(d)); //Do not compile
std::function<bool()> f = boost::bind(&Derived::Run,boost::ref(d)); //compile
```

It's not a major issue, since I can stick with boost, but I would really want to know what's the difference between the two.

I've checked few questions in here but I don't think how it will be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555566/is-there-any-difference-between-c11-stdbind-and-boostbind).
Checked stroustrup's site too [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-function), but I did not see anything that could explain this behaviour.
What am I missing here ?

Ps: I work with VS2012 Update 4, if this can help

Comment: Does [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1efb5c2d542e5958) work? If not, it could be a bug in one of the standard library implementations.

Comment: It does not compile, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 has a lot of bugs relating to `std::function` and `std::bind`. This is one of them; the code will work in both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013.

The best choice is to use Boost.Function and Boost.Bind exclusively.