# Casting function pointers to sasl_callback_ft

Tags: c++, function, casting, callback

I am writing C++ code which calls sasl_client_init().
I defined plugin functions such as:

```
int GetPluginPath(void *context,
  const char **path) {
```

However, the compiler doesn't allow me to assign function pointer to proc member of sasl_callback_t :

connection/connection-factory.cc:164:22: error: reinterpret_cast from 'int (SaslHandler::*)(void *, int, const char *)' to 'sasl_callback_ft' (aka 'int (*)()') is not allowed

```
callback->proc = reinterpret_cast<sasl_callback_ft> (&SaslHandler::SaslLogFn);
```

Any hint how sasl_callback_t should be initialized ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback

Comment: Partly but it's not even the same argument signature.

Comment: Background: more than one function pointer is passed in sasl_callback_t array to sasl_client_init().
Here is one more function to be passed:

    int SaslLogFn(void *context __attribute__((unused)),
      int priority,
      const char *message) {

Here is declaration of sasl_callback_t :

    typedef struct sasl_callback {
      unsigned long id;
      int (*proc)(void);   /* Callback function.  Types of arguments vary by 'id' */
      void *context;
    } sasl_callback_t;

Comment: Pardon for the formatting. See http://pastebin.com/EitMw5Jt