# invalid use of member in static member function - arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to call the keypad function into my own library. Before this I had an error "Invalid use of non-static error member function" and have changed the function into a static function. However since the keypad function is non-static, it still does not run.

This is the error.

> ```
> sketch\latch.cpp: In static member function 'static void latch::keypadEvent(KeypadEvent)':
>
> latch.cpp:18:11: error: invalid use of member 'latch::keypad' in static member function
>
>    switch (keypad.getState()){
>
>            ^
>
> In file included from sketch\latch.cpp:1:0:
>
> sketch\latch.h:20:12: note: declared here
>
>      Keypad keypad;
>
>             ^
>
> exit status 1
> invalid use of member 'latch::keypad' in static member function
> ```

My code

```
#include "latch.h"
latch doorlatch;

void setup(){
  doorlatch.begin(9600);
  }
 void loop(){
  doorlatch.main();
  }
```

h file

```
#include <Keypad.h>

#ifndef _latch_
#define _latch_

#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif

class latch {

  public:
    latch();
    void begin(int baudrate);
    void main();
    static void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input);
    Keypad keypad;

  private:
    const byte Rows = 4;
    const byte Cols = 4;

    char keys[4][4] = {
      {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
      {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
      {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
      {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
    };

    byte rowPins[4] = {7, 6, 5, 4};
    byte colPins[4] = { 11, 10, 9, 8 };
};

#endif
```

cpp file

```
latch::latch():keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, Rows, Cols ) {
}

void latch::begin(int baudrate){
  Serial.begin(baudrate);
  keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent);

}

void latch::main(){
  keypad.getKey();
}
void latch::keypadEvent(KeypadEvent input){
  switch (keypad.getState()){
  case PRESSED:
  Serial.print("Enter: ");
  Serial.println(input);
  delay(10);

  }
}
```

Can someone help me solve this ? Or should I use a different method ? such as declaring it as friend ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have conflicting requirements.

On the one hand, the signature of the callback function that is added via the `addEventListener()` method can only be something like

```
void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent key);
```

due to the library `Keypad.h`

On the other hand, you want to access the instance `Keypad keypad;` inside `class latch` from within the event listener, but `Keypad keypad` is not an input argument of the callback function nor visible in the global scope.

You have three possible choices:

- sub-class `class Keypad` and introduce a new method for adding a callback function which is either a *member instance* or a friend of `class latch`; or, alternatively, a function which accepts as additional parameter the reference to the `Keypad` object you want to have access to. [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback)
- Provide a unique instance of `Keypad` at the *Global Scope* using the **singleton pattern**, i.e. a static, factory method that always returns a reference to the same instance of `Keypad`. [More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

The latter could be as easy as making

```
 `Keypad keypad`
```

available at the global scope, and it is actually a much more preferable approach than the other.

Comment: how do I make it into a _Global Scope_ ? I thought putting 'Keypad keypad' into the class would've done the same job

Comment: That's not in the global scope. That's in the scope of an instance of `class latch`.