# Using a void function as a callback, convert from "std::function<void ()>?

Tags: c++, callback

I have a boost::Asio based serial port reader that uses a callback, as follows:

```
void received(const char *data, unsigned int len)
{

        string s(data, len);
        cout <<  s  << endl;    

}

int main()
{

    try {
        CallbackAsyncSerial serial("COM4", 115200);
        serial.setCallback(received);
        for(;;)
        {
            if(serial.errorStatus() || serial.isOpen()==false)
            {
                cerr<<"Error: serial port unexpectedly closed"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            char c;
            cin.get(c); //blocking wait for standard input
           serial.write(&c,1);
        }
        quit:
        serial.close();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cerr<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

}
```

This, as above, compiles and runs. Now I need to merge it into an existing class, so i have:

```
void MyClass::received(const char *data, unsigned int len)
{

        string s(data, len);
        cout <<  s  << endl;    

}

int MyClass::main()
{

    try {
        CallbackAsyncSerial serial("COM4", 115200);
        serial.setCallback(received); //COMPILE ERROR HERE
        for(;;)
        {
            if(serial.errorStatus() || serial.isOpen()==false)
            {
                cerr<<"Error: serial port unexpectedly closed"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            char c;
            cin.get(c); //blocking wait for standard input
           serial.write(&c,1);
        }
        quit:
        serial.close();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cerr<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

}
```

However, adding `MyClass::received` stops the compile, giving me:

```
Error (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void (const char *data, unsigned int len)" to "std::function<void (const char *, size_t)>"
```

I have tried adjusting it to:

`std::function< void() >received(const char *data, unsigned int len);`

But i see the same thing. 
What do i need to do here?

Comment: Like this?  `serial.setCallback(std::bind(&MyClass::received, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));`

Comment: Yep, exactly in this way.

Comment: Have you tried making your `MyClass:received` function a `static` member?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Right, mis-parsed the question.

Comment: Sadly the most direct duplicate is [stuck in pre-C++11 land](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback)... Do we not have a canonical dupe target for this?

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments by [rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8950365/rafix07)

What I needed was to adjust the `setCallback` line to:

```
serial.setCallback(
    std::bind(&MyClass::received, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Comment: Do you not have lambdas available? `std::bind` is basically obsolete since C++11...

Comment: How would this look using lambdas?

Comment: Like that `serial.setCallback([this] (auto data, auto len) { received(data, len); })`.

Comment: Also works great. Thank you! Is this the more recommended approach?

Comment: Yes it is. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlHi8txU4aQ)  for more details on the subject.