# Can't call Member function in a non member function

Tags: c++

I have a class and it has a member function and i want to call that member function in a non member function.

```
void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param);
class CMainClass
{

private:
// Xcoordinate of the click event
     int Xcoordinate;
public:
// Xcoordinate get method
         int CMainClass::GetXcoordinate()
         {
          return Xcoordinate;
         }

// Xcoordinate set method
         void CMainClass::SetXcoordinate(int newVal)
         {
           CMainClass::Xcoordinate = newVal;
         }

};


void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
      CMainClass::SetXcoordinate(x);

}
```

C++ a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Comment: If you have 10 different `CMainClass` objects, which of those do you expect the member function to be called on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a class member function as a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback)

Comment: Make `CMainDialog::SetXcoordinate()` static

Comment: The code you show is also invalid C++. You keep changing between `CMainClass` and `CMainDialog`, and `int CMainDialog::GetXcoordinate()` is not a valid function declaration inside a class.

Comment: I made the changes and I have only one CMainClass object.

Answer (score 0):

ignoring non-relevant issues with your code, you are calling a member function without creating an object.

In mouseEvent, you need to use an object to call SetXcoordinate.

```
void mouseEvent(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    //CMainClass obj();
    obj.SetXcoordinate(x);
}
```

The object creation doesn't have to be in the same function if you created it elsewhere.