# How do I hand over a pointer to a non-static member method to an extern "C" function?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, extern-c

I've got a class named *tmc*, which now contains (among other things, which are not relevant here) a private constructor, a static factory method, and an instance method named `ReadLoop (void*)`:

```cpp
extern "C" {
#include <pigpiod_if2.h>
}

class tmc {
public:
  static tmc* Initialize ();
  static int  main ();

private:
  void *ReadLoop (void *params);
  tmc ();
  pthread_t *tmc_receiver_reader;
};

tmc::tmc ()
: tmc_receiver_reader (start_thread (tmc::ReadLoop, NULL))
{
}

void* tmc::ReadLoop (void *params)
{
  return params;
}

tmc* tmc::Initialize ()
{
  tmc* instance = new tmc ();
  return instance;
}

int tmc::main ()
{
  return (tmc::Initialize ()) == NULL ? 0 : 1;
}
```

The issue is now the following: How shall I use the `ReadLoop` as a function pointer for use with the [`start_thread ()`](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pdif2.html#start_thread) function contained in `pigpiod_if2`? The code shown here doesn't compile because of the following error:

```cpp
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void* tmc::ReadLoop(void*)’
   tmc_receiver_reader  (start_thread (tmc::ReadLoop, NULL))
```

I've seen several questions here at SO with the same error message, but none of them was about a pointer to a non-static member method given to a C function. Please note that even if the object created here is a singleton, I can't make `ReadLoop ()` static. I'm using the g++ 6.5.0 on Raspbian Buster. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback   Basically make a static function and pass the this pointer as the userdata then the static function can call the member function.  And there is always std::bind

Comment: Sorry, this is a similar case, but not an identical one.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `std::bind` won't help get a C pointer to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simply no way to use a *non-static* class method where a standalone function is expected.  They are not compatible.

You are going to have to use a *static* or *non-member* proxy function instead.  Fortunately, `start_thread()` allows you to pass a user-defined parameter to the function, so you can use that to pass the `this` pointer of your `tmc` instance, eg:

```cpp
class tmc {
  ...
private:
  static void* ReadLoopProxy(void *params);
  void* ReadLoop();
  tmc ();
  pthread_t *tmc_receiver_reader;
};

tmc::tmc ()
  : tmc_receiver_reader (start_thread (tmc::ReadLoopProxy, this))
{
}

void* tmc::ReadLoopProxy(void *params)
{
    return static_cast<tmc*>(params)->ReadLoop();
}

void* tmc::ReadLoop()
{
  return NULL;
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Luckily the C interface provides a `void*` pass-back to help with this. You can use that to point to the correct `tmc` object:

```
extern "C" void* tmc_pigpio_ReadLoop_callback(void* userdata);
class tmc {
    // ...
private:
    void* ReadLoop();
    friend void* tmc_pigpio_ReadLoop_callback(void*);
    // ...
};

void* tmc_pigpio_ReadLoop_callback(void* userdata)
{
    auto* tmcp = static_cast<tmc*>(userdata);
    return tmcp->ReadLoop();
}

// Note "this" passed to start_thread.
tmc::tmc ()
: tmc_receiver_reader (start_thread (tmc_pigpio_ReadLoop_callback, this))
{
}
```

Or if you were already using the `void* userdata` for something different, add a `tmc*` pointer to a struct it points at, or create a new struct containing a `tmc*` pointer and the other data to pass.