# How to use std::bind with std::function in order to pass method as a callback?

Tags: c++

I found this answer on SO

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40944576/5709159

I made everything like in answer, but I get an error

there is my code

Method where I need to pass my callback

```
/*static*/ void Utils::copy_files(std::function<void(int, int)> progress_callback,
        std::string const & path_from,
        std::string const & path_to)
    {
....
    }
```

My callback implementation

```
void TV_DepthCamAgent::progress_callback(int count, int copied_file)
{
...
}
```

Usage

```
void TV_DepthCamAgent::foo()
{
...
auto callback = std::bind(&TV_DepthCamAgent::progress_callback,
        this);

    shared::Utils::copy_files(callback, path_from_copy, path_to_copy);
...
}
```

There is an error that I get

> SE0312 no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Binder" to "std::function" exists
>
> Error  C2664   'void shared::Utils::copy_files(std::function,const std::string &,const std::string &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::_Binder' to 'std::function'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error messages do not line up well with the code provided. To remove ambiguity, I recommend adjusting the presented code so that it does match. Perhaps make a [mcve] in order to simply the problem into something you can more easily experiment with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss placeholders:

```
auto callback = std::bind(&TV_DepthCamAgent::progress_callback,
                          this,
                          std::placeholders::_1,
                          std::placeholders::_2);
```

but simpler, IMO, is to use lambda:

```
auto callback = [this](int count, int copied_file){
     return this->progress_callback(count, copied_file);
};
```