# Passing a class method as function's argument

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

```
class ARRAY {
  public:
    int *array;

    ARRAY(int size);

    void INSERT(int data);
};

ARRAY::ARRAY(int size) {
    array = new int[size];
}

void ARRAY::INSERT(int data) {
    array[data] = data;
    return;
}
```

This is a class of array.
And I want to pass a ARRAY class' method to some function's argument that measure a runtime.

```cpp
typedef void (ARRAY::*arrFuncCall)(int);

clock_t measure_time(arrFuncCall func, int iterate) {
    clock_t start = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < iterate; i++)
        func(i);

    clock_t end = clock();

    return end - start;
}
```

But I keep seeing an error in

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < iterate; i++)
   func(i);
```

That `expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type` in `func`

Why am I seeing this error?

Comment: Is this for a C++ course? In actual C++ code you'd probably use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of function pointers. In object-oriented C++ code (as in most C++ code) function pointers are pretty much useless.

Comment: You need an instance of `Array` to call one of it's non-static member functions. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback), maybe even a dupe.

Comment: actually its DS course.,, maybe I should try find another way to implement this..

Comment: *meant `ARRAY`, whoops.

Comment: What's the objective here? Using a function pointer will be trouble unless it's literally just a plain (non-class) function, or at least a `static` one. If you just need to time a call, use a lambda. It's reliable, it works, and unless they're teaching you C++98 or C++79 or something equally ridiculous then you can surely use them.

Comment: *"measure a runtime"* -- a runtime of what? The time of inserting an element into an `ARRAY` using `ARRAY::INSERT()`? Well, you can specify "inserting" with your function pointer and "element" with `i`, but which `ARRAY`?