# Determine object and method in a functor using boost::function and boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I'd like to obtain the pointer to the object and an indication of which method the functor will call from a functor constructed using boost::function and boost::bind.
This will allow me to automatically determine the order in a which bunch of functors must be executed.

The following (pseudo) code (see **POINTER_OF** & **METHOD_OF**) shows what I'm trying to do:

```
class myClassA
{
  public:
    DoIt(int i) { return i+i; }
};

class myClassB
{
  public:
    DoItToo(double d) { return d*d; }
};

typedef boost::function0<int> Functor;

myClassA classA;
myClassB classB;

Functor funcA = boost::bind( &myClassA::DoIt, &classA, 10 );
Functor funcB = boost::bind( &myClassB::DoItToo, &classB, 12.34 );

// Create a vector containing some functors and try to determine the objects
// they are called upon and the methods they invoke
std::vector<Functor> vec;
vec.push_back( funcA );
vec.push_back( funcB );

for (int i = 0; i < vec.size();i++)
{
  if (POINTER_OF(vec[i]) == &classA)
  {
    // This functor acts on classA
    if (METHOD_OF(vec[i]) == &myClassA::DoIt)
    {
      // This functor calls the 'DoIt' method.
    }
    else if (METHOD_OF(vec[i]) == &myClassB::DoItToo)
    {
      // This functor calls the 'DoItToo' method.
    }
  }
  // etc...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: code what you wnat write looks ugly. sorry. please descirbe addtional information, what you wnat to do with information about pointer and method?

Comment: some style advice, rename "classA" -- it's not a class, it's an object that is an instance of a particular class.  "instanceA" would be fine; "instanceOfClassA" is particularly verbose, but would at least be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

I know that the following is not a strict answer to your question but.

Don't do this.
Use polymorphism instead. It is one of the strangest things I saw in my current project code: if function pointer points to "someFunction" - do some extra acctions.

You can add extra behavior without changing your classes much with Decorator design pattern. That will extend your myClassA::DoIt with Decorator::DoIt.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: Maybe my example isn't clear ;-)  I only need to determine the object and method called on it for a large list of functors to determine the execution order of the methods as they all have side-effects and depend on eachother (used in machine control - objects represent physical systems)

Comment: @lasser - that doesn't change the good sense of Mykola's answer. You need a list of objects which have a priority and a function.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can get the target of a boost function that is set to a boost bind (ie METHOD_OF). According to [this post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/12/145709.php) on the boost mailing list this is because the return type of bind is not formally specified.

Edit: Link to an earlier question that is some-what related to this question: [demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

`boost::function` objects are equality comparable, so you should be able to do stuff like

```
if (vec[i] == boost::bind( &myClassA::DoIt, &classA, 10 ))
{
   // ... this Functor calls DoIt on classA with argument 10
}
```

I suspect you're looking for something more general though.  Digging into the implementation details of `boost/function_equal.hpp` (ie `boost::bind`'s `function_equal_impl`) might give you some idea how to selectively test a subset of the `boost::bind` arguments.

But I really think youd be better off with a polymorphism-based solution, or just aggregating the function objects with some metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, timday. If I understand right, when I use equal_impl I will still face the problem of getting the object and method out of boost::bind... Comparing boost::bind instances also won't work as they are different when different parameters are passed.

Comment: The equality test implementation itself must have access to the object and method (to compare them), which is why I suggest looking at how those are implemented.