# callback method in pcap_loop

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to use the pcap_loop function in libpcab library in Linux with this prototype:

```
int pcap_loop(pcap_t *, int, pcap_handler, u_char *);
```

pcap_pkthdr is a function pointer:

```
typedef void (*pcap_handler)(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
```

In my program, I have defined the following method in class SniffEthernet:

```
void SniffEthernet::got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);
```

Now calling pcap_loop as below

```
pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, this->got_packet, NULL);
```

gives me the following compile-time error:

```
SniffEthernet.cc:139:58: error: cannot convert ‘VENTOS::SniffEthernet::got_packet’ from type ‘void (VENTOS::SniffEthernet::)(u_char*, const pcap_pkthdr*, const u_char*) {aka void (VENTOS::SniffEthernet::)(unsigned char*, const pcap_pkthdr*, const unsigned char*)}’ to type ‘pcap_handler {aka void (*)(unsigned char*, const pcap_pkthdr*, const unsigned char*)}’
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881896/using-a-c-class-member-function-cannot-be-static-as-a-c-callback-function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your callback function cannot be a member function (method).  Don't forget that member functions always have the hidden parameter `this`.

Your callback function must be either a namespace-level function or a static member of your class.

If you want to have your object available for your CB function, you can use the `user` member (the last argument of `pcap_loop()`, first member of the callback function), with proper type casts, to pass arbitrary data, which, in your case, shall be the object you're using for the capture.

The code below is **incomplete** and **untested**, but might give you an idea.

```
class SniffEther {
    private:
        pcap_t *cap_handler;
        char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
        /* capture-related data members (properties) */

    public:
        static friend void pkt_callback(u_char *user, const pcap_pkthdr *hdr, const u_char *bytes){
            SniffEther *sniffer=reinterpret_cast<SniffEther *>(user);
            /*
                Process header and bytes.

                You can call things like sniffer->somemethod(), and also
                access sniffer->someproperty.
            */
        }

        // constructor
        SniffEther(const char *if_name){
            cap_handler=pcap_create(if_name, errbuf);
            if(!cap_handler)
                throw runtime_error(errbuf);
            /* Set the many pcap_options (see pcap(3)). */
            if(pcap_activate(cap_handler)!=0){
                string error(pcap_geterr(cap_handler));
                pcap_close(cap_handler);
                throw runtime_error(error);
            }
        }

        ~SniffEther(){
            if(cap_handler)
                pcap_close(cap_handler);
        }

        void capture_loop(int pkt_count=-1){
            if(
                pcap_loop(
                    cap_handler, pkt_count, pkt_callback,
                    reinterpret_cast<u_char *>(this)
                )==-1
            )
                throw runtime_error(pcap_geterr(cap_handler));
        }
};
```

Comment: Awesome answer.  The reinterpret_cast call in the pcap_loop() call has a misplaced dereference operator but other than that this code works.