# Messaging system: Callbacks can be anything

Tags: c++, event-handling, boost-bind

I'm trying to write an event system for my game. The callbacks that my event manager will store can be both plain functions as well as functors. I also need to be able to compare functions/functors so I know which one I need to disconnect from the event manager.

• Initially I tried using boost::function; it handles functions and functors perfectly well, except it has no operator==, so I can't remove callbacks if I want to.

```
class EventManager
{
    typedef boost::function<void (boost::weak_ptr<Event>)> Callback;
    std::map<Event::Type, std::vector<Callback>> eventHandlerMap_;
};
```

• I also tried using boost::signal, but that also gives me a compilation problem related to operator==:

> binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Functor' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
void test(int c) {
    std::cout << "test(" << c << ")";
}

struct Functor
{
    void operator()(int g) {
        std::cout << "Functor::operator(" << g << ")";
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::signal<void (int)> sig;

    Functor f;

    sig.connect(test);
    sig.connect(f);

    sig(7);

    sig.disconnect(f); // Error
}
```

Any other suggestions about how I might implement this? Or maybe how I can make either boost:: function or boost::signal work? (I'd rather use boost:: function though, since I've heard signal is rather slow for small collections of items.)

---

**Edit:** This is the interface of that I'd like EventManager to have.

```
class EventManager
{
  public:
    void addEventHandler(Event::Type evType, Callback func);
    void removeEventHandler(Event::Type evType, Callback func);

    void queueEvent(boost::shared_ptr<Event> ev);
    void dispatchNextEvent();
};
```

Comment: @bdonlan The one in the signal example is from [boost::function_equal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/function_equal.html).

Comment: sorta dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89488/comparing-stdtr1function-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter, I found the solution. A little template magic and things become simple(r):

```
template<typename F>
void EventManager::removeEventHandler(Event::Type evType, F func)
{
    auto compare = [func](const Callback& other) -> bool {
        F const* f = other.target<F>();
        if (f == nullptr) return false;
        return *f == func;
    };

    std::vector<Callback>& callbacks = ...;
    auto pend = std::remove_if(callbacks.begin(), callbacks.end(), compare);
    callbacks.erase(pend, callbacks.end());
}


template<typename R, typename F, typename L>
void EventManager::removeEventHandler(
    Event::Type evType, const boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>& func)
{
    auto compare = [&func](const Callback& other) -> bool {
        auto const* f = other.target<boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>>();
        if (f == nullptr) return false;
        return func.compare(*f);
    };

    std::vector<Callback>& callbacks = ...;
    auto pend = std::remove_if(callbacks.begin(), callbacks.end(), compare);
    callbacks.erase(pend, callbacks.end());
}
```

I need to handle Boost.Bind objects separately because `operator==` doesn't actually do comparison for Bind objects, but produce a new functor that compares the result of the other two ([read more](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators)). To compare Boost.Bind you have to use the member function `compare()`.

The type `boost::_bi::bind_t` seems to be an internal type of Boost (I guess that's what the underscore in namespace '_bi' means), however it should be safe to use it as all overloads of `boost::function_equal` also use this type ([reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp)).

This code will work for all types of functors as long as there is an `operator==` defined *that does comparison*, or if you're using Boost.Bind. I had a superficial look into `std::bind` (C++0x), but that doesn't seem to be comparable, so it won't work with the code I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that most generic function wrappers do not support function equality.

Why is this? Well, just look at your functor there:

```
struct Functor
{
    void operator()(int g) {
        std::cout << "Functor::operator(" << g << ")";
    }
};
```

This `Functor` has no `operator==`, and therefore cannot be compared for equality. So when you pass it to `boost::signal` *by value*, a new instance is created; this will compare false for pointer-equality, and has no operator to test for value-equality.

Most functors don't, in fact, have value-equality predicates. It's not useful very much. The usual way to deal with this is to have a handle to the callback instead; boost::signals does this with its `connection` object. For example, take a look at this example from [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html#id2851651):

```
boost::signals::connection c = sig.connect(HelloWorld());
if (c.connected()) {
// c is still connected to the signal
  sig(); // Prints "Hello, World!"
}

c.disconnect(); // Disconnect the HelloWorld object
assert(!c.connected()); c isn't connected any more

sig(); // Does nothing: there are no connected slots
```

With this, `HelloWorld` doesn't need to have an `operator==`, as you're referring directly to the signal registration.

Comment: If I'm doing to save the connection object, I might as well use vector<boost::fucntion> instead and save the iterator instead, since functions are faster than signals. Isn't there a way to make boost::function compare memory addresses instead?

Comment: `boost::function` also captures by value, so the addresses will _never_ be the same. And I suspect signals won't be too much worse than a regular vector of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried libsigc and libsigc++? I started using them in linux and fell in love with them. I now use them in my Windows applications as well. I believe it is more extensible and flexible than boost. It is also a breeze to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you consider Don Clugston's "Member Function Pointers and the Fastest Possible C++ Delegates". You can find the article and download the code from here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx

Among many other benefits, his delegates provide comparison operators (==, !=, <) out of the box. I'm currently using them for a realtime system and find them excellent in every way. I do seem to recall we had to make a minor modification to fix a compiler portability issue; but, that experience will vary based on platform etc.

Also, the article is several years old so you may want to google around for updated code/discussion regarding this delegate implementation if you run into any problems.