# Help with boost bind/functions

Tags: c++, lua, function-pointers, boost-bind, boost-function

I have this function signature I have to match

```
typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State *L);//target sig
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
    //somewhere else... 
    ...
registerFunction<LuaEngine>("testFunc", &LuaEngine::testFunc, this);
    ...

    //0 arg callback
void funcCallback0(boost::function<void ()> func, lua_State *state)
{
    func();
}

template<typename SelfType>
void registerFunction(const std::string &funcName, boost::function<void (SelfType*)> func, SelfType *self)
{
            //funcToCall has to match lua_CFunction
    boost::function<void (lua_State *)> funcToCall = boost::bind(&LuaEngine::funcCallback0, this,
        boost::bind(func, self), _1);
    lua_register(_luaState, funcName.c_str(), funcToCall);
}
```

However, at `lua_register(_luaState...`, it's still complaining about conversion issues

> Error 1   error C2664:
>   'lua_pushcclosure' : cannot convert
>   parameter 2 from
>   'boost::function' to
>   'lua_CFunction'

Anyone know how this can be solved?

Comment: A more broad question that touches the same general problem of converting `boost::function` to plain C pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be solved directly. Lua API wants a plain function pointers from you - that's just a code pointer, and nothing else. Meanwhile, `boost::function` is a function object, and there's no way it could possibly be convertible to a plain function pointer, because - roughly speaking - it captures not just the code, but also the state. In your example, the captured state is the value of `self`. So it has a code pointer for the code, and some data - and the target API expects just the code pointer.

Comment: Please read the answer I just posted. My original suspicion was similar to yours (in that a func ptr can't capture state), but it turns out it can through some nice magic.

Comment: Nope, you're wrong. From the Boost docs (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/function_base.html#id2623958-bb): "`template<typename Functor> Functor* target();` - If this stores a target of type Functor, returns the address of the target. Otherwise, returns the NULL pointer." - and in your case, the result of `bind` will not store target of type `lua_CFunction`. There's no magic there (well, there's no magic in general). It is not possible to squeeze random 8 bytes into 4.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler cant deduce the template parameter because there is an implicit conversion.

You need to store the function pointer into a function object.

```
function<int(lua_State *)> f = boost::bind(&LuaEngine::testFunc, this)
registerFunction<LuaEngine>("testFunc", f);
```

And your function expects a void return type and that is needed to change to int too.

Comment: I changed the return type to an int. Forgot it initially.

Comment: the example I give should work. The reason not to work is for your example. sorry about the confusion.