# Using Objects into a Glut Display Function

Tags: c++, glut, freeglut

i'm having trouble using an object in a glut DisplayFunction.

```
class Modelisation
{
private:
    int hauteur, largeur, x, y;
    Camera *Cam;

    void DisplayFunction ();
    static void RedisplayFunction (int, int);

public:
    Modelisation (int argc, char **argv, char[]);
    ~Modelisation ();

    void StartMainLoop();
};
```

Modelisation.cpp

```
Modelisation::Modelisation (int argc, char **argv, char windowName [])
{
    Cam = new Camera;
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutCreateWindow (windowName);
};
void Modelisation::StartMainLoop()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(DisplayFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(DisplayFunction);
    glutReshapeFunc(RedisplayFunction);
    glutMainLoop(); 
}
void Modelisation::DisplayFunction()
{
    glClearDepth (1);
    glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
    glLoadIdentity ();
    Cam->Render ();
    glFlush ();
    glutSwapBuffers ();
}
```

glutDisplayFunc(DisplayFunction);
glutIdleFunc(DisplayFunction);

This doesn't work.
I know that i can declare DisplayFunction as a static member, but this won't allow me to use the Cam Object, any idea ?

Thx !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, data members and methods that a `static` method uses must also be declared `static`.  The easiest way out of this is to declare `Cam` to be `static`.

You'll also have to initialize it statically, that is, in your implementation file:

```
Modelisation::Camera* Cam = new Camera();
```

(Note that, depending on how else `Cam` is used, you might open yourself up to the [static initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14).)

Comment: I'm sorry to ask that but how do i declare a static object Cam in a header file ?

Comment: You declare it as `static Camera* Cam;` in your header file.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, this works perfectly. I always get perfect answer when i ask questions on this forum. Thank you !!

Comment: Great! If you're happy with an answer, then you can mark it as "accepted" to let everyone know.  The person who answered also gets reputation points. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, because your `void DisplayFunction ();` is not static, and glutDisplayFunc expects a function pointer. Change your Modelisation class to this :

```
class Modelisation
{
private:
    int hauteur, largeur, x, y;
    Camera *Cam;

    static void DisplayFunction ();
    static void RedisplayFunction (int, int);

public:
    Modelisation (int argc, char **argv, char[]);
    ~Modelisation ();

    void StartMainLoop();
};
```

and it will work

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working, because my object Cam is not static.

Comment: you have to pass a function pointer to glutDisplayFunc - no way around it

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is essentially to use a non-static member function as a C callback, which is one of the ridiculous hard parts of C++.

A good overview why this doesn't work easily in C++03 is given in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer) and examples to work around.