# No target() of boost::function of a member function

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to get a pointer to a function in this way:

```
 boost::function<void(float)> Function;
 Function = boost::bind(&myClassType::myMemberFunction, this, _1);
 void(*)(float) finalFunction = *Function.target<void(*)(float)>();
/* crash becouse Function.target<void(*)(bool)>() is null */
```

But I can not get the pointer. Where I am wrong?
Did I do something that is not allowed?

(I have to pass finalFunction to lua_register.)

Comment: Thing about what you're trying to do. A function pointer can only point at an existing function somewhere in compiled code, yet you want one to point at a dynamically-binded function; not possible. You need to use upvalues for your Lua functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function::target()` is defined (I'm using the C++11 draft, which I think is a bit more clear than [boost's reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/function_base.html#id403340-bb)) as follows:

per C++0x n3290 20.8.11.2.5[func.wrap.func.targ]/3

> Returns: If target_type() == typeid(T) a pointer to the stored function target; otherwise a null pointer.

In your case, `T` is your type `void(*)(float)`, but `Function.target_type()` is not that at all, it is the type of the boost expression used to initialize boost::function.

So in short, yes, this is not allowed. The workarounds are not obvious, but here's one: [demote boost::function to a plain function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer/3453616#3453616)

Comment: I tried it, but with no success :(
I got this error: "invalid static_cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘int (*)(lua_State*)’"