# Creating a function (of fewer parameters) from another function

Tags: c++

I would like to do the following. Say I have this:

```
void f(const char* c) {
    // Do stuff with c
}

void g(const char* c, int x, int y) {
    // Do other stuff
}
```

What I'd like to do is to create a function from g that takes a const char* c. That is:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 9;
expression(g, a, b)("Hi!");
```

Preferably, `expression(g)` can be stored in a variable as well. I'm not sure how to declare this variable either.

I have tried using boost::bind; however boost::bind returns a boost::function, and I would like a normal C++ function pointer. Additionally, I also saw this thread:
[demote boost::function to a plain function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer/3453616#3453616)
And neither of the top two solution will work. My function f is constrained to take one parameter (no void* user_data pointer). The reason I need this is that I have a third function, h, that takes in a function of one argument, namely a const char* and does things with it. I'd like to be able to pass in a form of g to h.

```
h(f) // Valid
h(expression(g, a, b)) // Would like for this to be valid, too
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is, do tell :).

Answer (score 2):

Use `bind`:

```
#include <functional>

auto h = std::bind(g, std::placeholders::_1, 5, 9);

h("hi");
```

`bind` makes copies of the arguments, so beware if you're planning on taking arguments by reference (in which case you may want `std::ref`). Try to keep the result type `auto` to avoid unnecessary conversions.

---

To get a normal C++ function:

```
void h(char const * s) { g(s, 5, 9); }
```

Or:

```
void (*ph)(char const *) = [](const char * s) { g(s, 5, 9); };
```

Or for the insane:

```
struct Foo { static void bar(char const * s) { g(s, 5, 9); } };
void (*qh)(char const *) = &Foo::bar;
```

Usage:

```
h("hi");
ph("hi");
Foo::bar("hi");
qh("hi");
```

Comment: I've already tried bind, but like I said bind::boost returns a boost::function. What I'd like is a normal c++ function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I should have been more clear. I'd like the arguments to g (The 5 and 9 in your example) to be parameters as well. That is, 
    void t(int a, int b) {
        return expression(g, a, b); // Returns a function that takes a const char*
    }

    t(3, 5)("Hello"); // g("Hello", 3, 5);

Comment: You can't have plain function pointer with expression you wish. first expression would first have to store 3 and 5 parameters, and with second () statement it would have to execute g. So it's either lambda, binded function, or custom struct. TBH I don't see reason for what you want to accompish.