# Simple template code compiles in Visual Studio but not with LLVM

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

What I'm trying to do is create a template function that stores a generic function pointer and information about how to cast to it's actual type. This is being used by my script binding API to make C++ function calls from Python for a game engine. In the process of porting this to OSX using XCode4 with LLVM, I have run into an error. This sample code compiles and runs fine in Visual Studio 2012, but gives me the error "No matching function for call to 'Call'" with LLVM.

```
#include <iostream>

void testfun (int i)
{
  std::cout << "Hello World " << i << std::endl;
}

typedef void BasicFunction ();

template <BasicFunction* fn, typename T0>
void Call (void(*f)(T0), T0 i)
{
  reinterpret_cast<decltype(f)>(fn)(i);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  Call<reinterpret_cast<BasicFunction*>(testfun)>(testfun, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Is this non standard code? A bug with LLVM? Or is there just a better way to accomplish the same task? Note: The function pointer must come first in the template so that the function information can be deduced automatically.

Comment: Looks like a pretty unnecessary way to say `std::bind`.

Comment: std::bind doesn't give me something I can use as a function pointer. The Python binding api requires I give it function pointers of a uniform signature.

Comment: Oops, I missed that part. It's a pity, since that or variadic templates are perfect depending on your needs.

Comment: Wow, gcc 4.7 crashes while compiling this snippet. BTW: `reinterpret_cast`ing a function that takes one argument, to a function type that takes no arguments is probably UB.

Comment: UB? It should be safe as long as it is casted back to the right type before using it, as with using reinterpret_cast for anything. g++ 4.2 complains that it can't do the cast because a function pointer cast isn't a constant expression ... which doesn't make sense to me.  
  
Another case where Microsoft will compile something that it probably shouldn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang is correct. I believe 14.3.2p1 rules out this:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter
>   shall be one of:
>
> — a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an
>   object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage
>   or **a function with external or internal linkage**, including
>   function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static
>   class members, **expressed (ignoring parentheses) as &
>   id-expression**, except that the & may be omitted if the name refers
>   to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding
>   template-parameter is a reference; or

The important part is `expressed (ignoring parentheses) as & id-expression`. The expression must have an `&`, however you cannot take the address of an rvalue. So this pretty much rules out any casts.

Also, from 5.19p2 `reinterpret_cast` is illegal in constant expressions:

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>
> — a reinterpret_cast (5.2.10);

Comment: That is really annoying, do you know of an alternate solution to what I am trying to do?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your use is, but maybe [this question might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer).

Comment: Sadly it's not exactly what I need. My goal is to wrap any function into a uniform signature that can be given to (currently) the cpython api to allow python scripts to call c++ functions in my game engine. And python doesn't give any kind of "user data" option when calling a function.