# Trying to get plain function pointer from std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, function-pointers

I'm trying to get plain function pointer from some std::function. The task has been discussed number of times at SO ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282372/demote-boostfunction-to-a-plain-function-pointer/282433#282433)) and was admitted unsolvable. But I tried such a solution (I fixed the function pointer signture and degenerated the usage of a plain function pointer for the sake of simplicity):

```
#include <functional>

typedef int(*fp)(int);

template<int idx, typename F>
struct wrap_f_struct {
    static F impl;

    static int f(int a) { return impl(a); }    
};

template<int idx, typename F>
fp wrap_f(F f) { 
    wrap_f_struct<idx, F>::impl = f;
    return wrap_f_struct<idx, F>::f;
}

int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int main() {
    using namespace std::placeholders; 
    std::function<int(int)> add2 = std::bind(add, _1, 2);

    (wrap_f<1>(add2))(1);
}
```

Well, this isn't linking for some reason I can't understand:

```
/tmp/ccrcFz32.o: In function `int (*wrap_f<1, std::function<int (int)> >(std::function<int (int)>))(int)':
cast_fp_min.cpp:(.text._Z6wrap_fILi1ESt8functionIFiiEEEPS1_T0_[_Z6wrap_fILi1ESt8functionIFiiEEEPS1_T0_]+0x10): undefined reference to `wrap_f_struct<1, std::function<int (int)> >::impl'
/tmp/ccrcFz32.o: In function `wrap_f_struct<1, std::function<int (int)> >::f(int)':
cast_fp_min.cpp:(.text._ZN13wrap_f_structILi1ESt8functionIFiiEEE1fEi[_ZN13wrap_f_structILi1ESt8functionIFiiEEE1fEi]+0x10): undefined reference to `wrap_f_struct<1, std::function<int (int)> >::impl'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My question is: can someone explain me the exact reason why this linkage error occurs?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with functions or pointers or templates. It's just the tired old "define your static class members" problem from C++101.

Comment: Your "solution" is also massively non-reentrant. It's basically impossible to *store* the result of `wrap_f` in a meaningful way.

Comment: @KerrekSB if you use different integer constants when instantiating wrap_t (1 in example), you can store return values safely, afaics.

Comment: It's technically safe, but multi-threaded programs tend to be big. This type of solution scales poorly, and makes programs very hard to debug.

Comment: @MSalters can't see, what problems could arise in MT programs due to this solution (except those, which could arise in any MT programs and don't depend on this particular approach), would you please expand on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static member variables are only *declared* in a structure/class. They need to be *defined* as well, which you do not do.

Add e.g.

```
template<int idx, typename F>
F wrap_f_struct<idx, F>::impl;
```

Comment: ouups… shame on me. Thank you!